# Probability for rolling an odd number and tossing a coin on heads

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

A coin is tossed and a die rolled. Find the probability of getting a head and an odd number. The answer is $\frac{1}{4}$.

My reasoning is that rolling an odd number is $\frac{1}{2}$, and tossing a coin on heads is $\frac{1}{2}$. So $0.5 \times 0.5$ = $\frac{1}{4}$.

Is this basically it?

Comment: Yes. The outcome of the die is independent of the outcome of the coin: $P(d\cap c)=P(d|c)\cdot P(c)=P(d)\cdot P(c)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is it.
The coin and the die are independent of each other, so you can just multiply the probabilities.